# Bootstrap: Semi-transparent navbar overlay on carousel breaks page css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, overlay, carousel, navbar

I am trying to implement a transparent bootstrap navbar overlay onto bootstrap carousel and i am having a bit of an issue, i can get the navbar exactly in the position that i want it to be in with the code provided below, however the issue is that this breaks the page css and content that should be below the slider then appears over it as well as the navbar.

css:

```
.navbar-wrapper {
    position:relative;
}
.carousel {
    position:absolute;
    top:60px;
}
.carousel-inner {
    width: 100%; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
.navbar {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    z-index:10;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.85;
    width:100%;
}
```

As you can see from the navbar html i have only added the navbar class of "navbar" as i just wanted to use less code until i get the navigation positioned where i wanted it to be, i will add the other lines when the page breaking issue is fixed. Leaving the code in or out does not change the page breaking issue so i am guessing it is to do with the actual css for the carousel that is causing the issue.
html:

```
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
        <div class="navbar">
        </div>   
    </div><!-- /navbar-wrapper -->


    <!-- simple bootstrap carousel -->
     <div id="carousel-generic" class="carousel slide small-browser-margins reposition-top" data-ride="carousel">

        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
           <li data-target="#carousel-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
           <li data-target="#carousel-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
           <li data-target="#carousel-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
           <li data-target="#carousel-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner">
           <div class="item active">
              <img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
           </div>
           <div class="item">
              <img src="images/image2.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
           </div>
           <div class="item">
              <img src="images/image3.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
           </div>
           <div class="item">
              <img src="images/image4.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive">
           </div>       
        </div>
     </div><!-- /#carousel-generic -->
```

Image added for clarity of the issue, all text should be below the carousel.
[image: Image of problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh dear... a cup of tea and another look at things and this was all i had to do, a very small change to css:

```
.navbar-wrapper {
    position:relative;
}
.carousel {
    top:0;
}
.carousel-inner {
    width: 100%; 
    overflow: hidden;
    }
.navbar {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    z-index:10;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.85;
    width:100%;
}
```